# xml generation using sql 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have a stored procedure that returns a single recordset. is it possible to convert it into xml like below

```
<employee>
    <firstname>x</name>
    <lastname>x</name>
    <dob>x</dob>
</employee>
```

using some simple options in sql 2000?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE 1 = 1
FOR XML AUTO
```

Instead of the AUTO, you can use RAW, EXPLICIT or PATH (see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107(v=SQL.90).aspx), but AUTO generally does what you want.

I can only find notes on MSDN for SQL 2008 and 2005 but I'm sure I've used this on 2000 before...

Comment: SQL Server 2000 does **NOT** support `FOR XML PATH` - that's a new feature in the 2005 versions

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Skrealin

the query below works

select * from Mytable employee for xml auto , elements